# make apigee x setup more secure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apigee

We plan to move from Apigee Edge to Apigee X. Unfortunately I still do have a open security related question where I do not find any suitable informations.

Do I need an additional service for Intrusion Detection like Cloud IDS or is that already built in Apigee X?

Answer (score 0):

For the best practices there could be no. of ways but, in general the service would be the same and Apigee x is different from Apigee in multiple ways.

1. You can deploy 50 proxies to an environment.
2. API proxies are immutable when they are deployed.
3. You can do your own configuration/setup in Apigee.
4. By using a customer encryption key all the KVM’s are encrypted.
5. Admin authentication and Admin API endpoints are different.
6. GCP IAM and RBAC govern admin identity and operators.

You can have look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/fundamentals/best-practices-api-proxy-design-and-development).